# CSS does not work for Firefox

Tags: html, css

I have a css file and one of the classes is as follows:

```
.thumnail { 
    padding-left:100px;
    padding-top:20px;
}
```

When i refer to the class thumnail for a table `<tr>` in Internet Explorer it works and in Firefox it does not. Can any one help me out please?

Comment: are you serious?? ("</td></tr>" - do you seriously think that this is a relevant code part??) I think you have to finish your post...or delete it.

Comment: Relax guys! Needed some editing!! :)

Comment: Are any of the CSS rules from the file being followed?

Answer (score 3):

From the [specification for padding](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#padding-properties):

> Applies to: all elements except table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group and table-column

A `<tr>` element is, by default, `display: table-row` so `padding` should not have any effect on it.

If you want to adjust the space between `<td>` and `<th>` elements, you need to use the [`border-spacing`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#propdef-border-spacing) property (and apply it to the `<table>` element).